# Is it possible to find the location from background in iPhone 3G, 3GS

Tags: iphone

I am making an app in which i need to find the location from  background when userpress the home button, my app works fine on iPad2 and it gets updated,however its not working on iPhone, apart from iPhone 4, previous version of iPhone, is it possible to track update on that older version of iPhone leaving iPhone 4

Comment: iPhone 3G does not support multi-tasking. When you hit home, the app gets terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention that your app is running on iPad and iPhone, I assume that you are not asking about how to get the location when the app is running in background and that you are doing correctly as explained [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

As to the rest, your problem may have to do with background processing being only available starting from iOS 4.0.

So, more than the specific model of iPhone, what matters is the iOS version that is installed on your device (or if it can be installed).

Answer (score 1):

As Badgerr commented, iPhone 3GS was the first version of the iPhone to support multi tasking. Previous versions of the iPhone are not capable of tracking the user location without the app running in the foreground. As soon as a third party app enters the background it gets closed.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4211:

> Multitasking in iOS 4 is supported on iPhone 3GS or later, iPod touch
>   (3rd generation or later), and all iPad models.

Comment: No true, the iPhone 3GS is capable of running app in the background just as the iPhone 4. You can even register for location change in the background.